# ios: images sometimes not loading from bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Sometimes (RARELY but still a problem), users have reported missing images in my app. The images load fine on 3 iPhones I use for testing and on most users devices so I cannot imagine the problem is in the code.

See screenshot here: the avatar/profile image is missing, and two icons in the big buttons (loaded via IB from bundle) are also missing. The screenshot is from one of the users. My tests in both Test and Prod are showing the images just fine. Anybody got an idea?

[image: Screenshot from user]

Comment: Maybe, the same name, or, support retina (a.png, a@2x.png). Check it again

Comment: I have checked 100 times :) The app is only supported on iOS 7 so it only supports retina images, and all are @2x.png. And besides it works on almost all users devices, but only fails on some. I cant imagine what difference there is between two of the same devices and same iOS.

Comment: Recently, I had problem with iPad mini retina (frame of this device is different with other devices). I think you create new project and test error image with this error device.

Answer (score 1):

Probably problem can be in missing resources for retina or non-retina displays.
E.g. You have avatar for non-retina resolution only and you have incorrect naming - then on retina there will be no image.

Also make sure that you have corresponding images naming:
If you are not using image assets, for each image you should have next resources
non-retina resolution: my_pic_name.png
retina resolution: my_pic_name@2x.png

If you are using image assets - make sure that "1x" and 2x" cells for expected resource name a filled.

Comment: I have checked 100 times :) The app is only supported on iOS 7 so it only supports retina images, and all are @2x.png. And besides it works on almost all users devices, but only fails on some. I cant imagine what difference there is between two of the same devices and same iOS.

Comment: Do I need to have both retina AND nonretina even if app is only supported on retina devices? and why does it work on so many iPhones and fail on some (same hardware) ? doesnt make sense.

Comment: If you support only retina devices you do not need do add images for non-retina - you just need to make correct naming for those images/assets and use them correctly in code/IB.

Comment: BTW - supporting only iOS 7 does not mean supporting of retina devices only. iOS 7 perfectly runs on iPad2/iPad Mini and these devices have non-retina display. So for example if your application even is for iPhones only, users can run them on iPad as well, and if application is started on iPad with non-retina images if there are some missing resources for non-retina resolution you can receive such reports.

Comment: thanks but I think i got that one covered. The error reports I have received were on an iOS 7.1 on an iPhone 5s. So it should work. I have no access to the device with the error, so it is a bit hard to diagnose it, now that my own works fine. I will report if I can provoke the error on my own.